# python-docx no cambia el tamaño de la fuente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de generar un archvio .docx con python-docx, pero no cambia el tamaño de la funte este es mi codigo

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
import datetime


def imprimir_ticket():
    doc = Document()
    run = doc.add_paragraph('dsjf').add_run()
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.size = Pt(12)
    doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/dsjff.docx')
imprimir_ticket()
```

mantiene el tamaño de fuente en 11pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la línea `run = doc.add_paragraph('dsjf').add_run()`, efectivamente `run` es un objeto `Run` (elementos `<w:r>`) pero que no tiene contenido, **el texto lo agregas mediante el inicializador de `Paragraph`**.

Cuando se añade texto a un objeto `Paragraph` ya sea al inicializar o posteriormente mediante el atributo `text` lo que ocurre es que se crea un objeto `Run` que sobreescribe el contendio completo del párrafo y al que se le asingna el texto. En tu caso, creas implícitamente un objeto `Run` mediante el inicializador de `Paragraph` con el texto y luego añades otro objeto `Run` explícitamente, sin contenido y al que le modificas la fuente.
Ten en cuenta que la fuente es una propiedad que pertenece a `Run`, no al `Paragraph` contenedor.

Podrías acceder a este objeto mediante el atributo `runs` de la instancia de `Paragraph` y modificar la fuente:

```
doc = Document()
paragraph = doc.add_paragraph('dsjf')
run = paragraph.runs[0]
font = run.font
font.name = 'Calibri'
font.size = Pt(12)
```

Ahora bién, es mejor simplemente separar la instanciación del `Paragraph` y de su `Run` (esto permitirá hacer referencia al párrafo posteriormente sin complicaciones) y **añadir  explícitamente el texto mediante la instancia del `Run`**:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
import datetime


def imprimir_ticket():
    doc = Document()
    par = doc.add_paragraph()
    run = par.add_run('dsjf')
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.size = Pt(12)
    doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save('C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/dsjff.docx')

imprimir_ticket()
```

Puedes definir tus propios estilos personalizados para facilitar la tarea si vas a usar e intercalar varios estilos:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE


document = Document()

styles = document.styles
charstyle = styles.add_style('Calibri_12', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
obj_font = charstyle.font
obj_font.size = Pt(12)
obj_font.name = 'Calibri'

styles.add_style('TNR_15', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
obj_font = charstyle.font
obj_font.size = Pt(15)
obj_font.name = 'Times New Roman'

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run("Hola Stack Overflow en Español\n", style='Calibri_12')
paragraph.add_run("Adios Stack Overflow en Español", style='TNR_15')
document.add_page_break()
document.save('hola.docx')
```